# Install mapnik linux Debian

Tags: debian, gis, mapnik

I install mapnik LInux Debian 7.2 on the instructions https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/DebianInstallation.

In response to receiving:

```
E: Unable to locate package libmapnik2-2.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmapnik2-2.0'
E: Unable to locate package mapnik-utils
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `apt-get update` before?

Answer (score 1):

You should install current mapnik version >=2.2 on debian from source. Dependencies are listed in your link, see also Ubuntu Installation [from source](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation#wiki-install-mapnik-from-source).

Packages are for old version 2.0